# Silex Routing Issue - Remove page name and directory name

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, symfony1, silex

First of all, I am new in `Silex PHP Framework` and i am trying to create one RESTApi for my Android app.

My Directory Structure

> abc
>   ----vendor
>   ----web
>   --------index.php
>   --------.htaccess
>   ----composer.json
>   ----composer.lock

my `Index.php` File coding

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/hello/{id}', function ($id) use($app) {
    return 'Hello '.$app->escape($id); 
});

$app->get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello!';
});

$app->run();
```

my .htaccess file coding

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/index\.php/(.*) /$1
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /abc/web/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?!web/).*)$ web/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

When i hit this URL `http://127.0.0.1/abc/web/`

it's work perfectly good and get response `Hello!`

but when i hit URL like this `http://127.0.0.1/abc/web/hello/123`

so i got Error like this

```
Not Found

The requested URL /abc/web/hello/123 was not found on this server.
```

And if i hit this URL `http://127.0.0.1/abc/web/index.php/hello/123` so it's work good and i got response OK. `Hello 123`

So, `MY QUESTION` is how i remove page name `index.php` and `dir` name `web` from my URL and i want my URL to look like this `http://127.0.0.1/abc/hello/123`

Is that possible ? and how ?

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So what's happening is that your rewrite rule isn't sending requests through the Silex front controller (`index.php`) which is required for getting friendly routing working. I'd strongly suggest reading up on the [routing documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#routing) as well as the [example Apache configuration](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html#apache).

To sort this, the following may work for your .htaccess:

```
    RewriteRule ^((?!web/).*)$ web/index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

I'm not entirely sure what the `^((?!web/).*)$` regex is meant to achieve, ideally it would be:

```
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

As per the documentation. Your requirements though may dictate you fiddling with this until it works though.